# Why i get grandchilds excuted multiple times?

Tags: c, linux, process

I am trying to create a PARENT process a CHILD 1 and CHILD 1.1 and CHILD 1.2
(in parent a i read a file then i pass the text to child 1 with pipes and child 11 and child12 print some specific text like upperCaseCounter and lowerCaseCounter)

But when i tested it i saw that the grandchildren get executed multiple times, and parent doesn't even get executed.

Can someone help with 2 fixes?
1)Have the processes executed one time each. 
2)Have the processes executed in that order: 
PARENT-> CHILD 1-> CHILD 1.1 -> CHILD 1.2.

Code here:

```
#define BUFFSIZE 1024
int file;//global file variable
int n;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   //parent reads from file all
   //child 1 get words (numerics discarded) 
   //child 1.1 printf lowercase letters
   //child 1.2 printf uppercase letters


   //create the processes here
   pid_t pid; 
   pid = fork();

   //check for error
   if( pid < 0 ) {
       printf("Process error\n");
   }



   if( pid > 0 ){
       //we are in parent process 
       printf("Parent process\n");
   } 

   if( pid == 0) {
       //we are in child 1 process
       printf("Child 1 process\n");


       //child 1.1
       pid_t pid_11;
       pid_11 = fork();

       //child 1.2
       pid_t pid_12;
       pid_12 = fork();

       if(pid_11 == 0){
           printf("Child 11\n");
       }

       if(pid_12 == 0) {
           printf("Child 12\n");
       }

   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: After you `fork` [into `pid_11`], both the parent _and_ child will then `fork` [into `pid_12`]. You need to add tests similar to `if (pid == 0)` to the later code [as you did in the upper section]. Also, [side note] you're creating zombie processes because you don't do any `wait` calls

Comment: I think i understand, i will try too see now.

Comment: Can somene help me with "wait()" calls ? I really didn't understand how to use those

Comment: Read about `wait()` [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitid.2.html). It also has an example at the bottom of the page.